# Asterisk работа с json

Tags: json, asterisk

Подскажите если Asterisk умеет работать с json форматом!

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Мне нужно распарсить строку вида

["item1","item2","item3","item4"]

Comment: Тогда можете использовать сторонний скрипт и вызывать его через AGI. По выполнении передадите в asterisk результат. https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_AGI

Answer (score 1):

Можно через сторонний скрипт, а можно через  JSONELEMENT https://github.com/drivefast/asterisk-res_json

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(CURL_RESULT=${CURL(http://domain.com/test.json)})
same => n,Set(result=${JSONELEMENT(CURL_RESULT,result/subfield)})
same => n,GotoIf($["${result}" = "1"]?result1:result2)
same => n(result1),Verbose(Result 1)
```

Comment: Сделал проще,вместо джейсона вернул стринг разделенный запятыми,и уже в астериске с помощью функции SHIFT спарсил